# Simple BackboneJS 1.1.2 script with jquery 1.11.0 throws Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method '_reset'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to write a very simple BackboneJS script and I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method '_reset'
```

Here's the code in it's most simple format:

```
var myAPP = {};

myAPP.attribute = Backbone.Model.extend({});

myAPP.attributes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: myAPP.attribute
});

myAPP.indexView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.attributes = options.attributers;
        alert('Works');
    }
});

var view = new myAPP.indexView({attributes: new myAPP.attributes()});
```

The error is reproducible in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpu46/1/

It seems to be something with jQuery. Interestingly enough I can switch from jQuery to Zepto and things work fine. However, in my environment Zepto isn't an option so I need to figure out why BackboneJS doesn't like jQuery. I've searched around for answers but no luck. Maybe you guys can shed some light.

Comment: Backbone.View.attributes is used by backbone to set the Backbone.View.el property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "attributes" is a keyword for Backbone.js, because when I change attributes by attrs it works.

```
var myAPP = {};

myAPP.attribute = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {}
});

myAPP.attributes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: myAPP.attribute,
    initialize: function () {}
});

myAPP.indexView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        $('body').append(this.$el);
        this.attributes = options.attrs;
        console.log(this.attributes);
    }
});

var view = new myAPP.indexView({attrs: new myAPP.attributes()});
```

Look http://jsfiddle.net/wLTT7/9/